# How to programmatically clear all replication options in a Lotus Database using java

Tags: java, replication, lotus-notes

Is there a *working* way to remove all replication options set in a Lotus Notes database (using java)?

I have tried the following approach:

I changed replication settings (added formula, enabled/disabled flags in "Advanced" tab, etc).

Then I invoked the code:

```
Replication replication = currentDb.getReplicationInfo();
ReplicationEntry any2AnyEntry = replication.getEntry("-", "-");
ReplicationEntry any2ThisSrvEntry = replication.getEntry("-", currentDb.getServer());
....
```

if an entry is not null I invoke `someReplicationEntry.remove();` and after that I call `replication.save();`

But when I check replication options in the Notes client, there are the same settings, which were before.

How can I reset replication options to the state like the state for a just created Notes database? Is there a way? (tried `replication.reset()` with save, but without success).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call the replication.save() after the remove() as you are just creating the document again.

Sample code detailed here:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_REMOVE_METHOD_RE_JAVA.html